# How to get data from firestore and set it to the input box using react js

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to react javascript . I want to create a my profile page for my web application project in which there will be a form using which the data will be inserted in to the firebase. Now i want to fetch the data on the same form so that user can update or edit teh detais which he has filled. In that page i want to get the data from the firestore in the form and the i  have to edit the data whichever i feel like and then again update it to the database. But i don't know how can i get the data from firestore and set it to the input box. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: need more information about how data is structured, and how the application is coded. some code snippets will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you but i have already got the solution from below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but I will give an example of how to get for example the name from firebase and set that as the current state for the input box. If you change the state of the input box, the state changes and when you feel ready you can submit the changed credentials. Let me know if this wasn't what you were looking for.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  function fetchUserCreds() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        setName(snapshot.name);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  function changeCreds() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .update({
        name: name
      })
      .then(() => {
        //Do something
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <button title="Submit" onClick={() => changeCreds()} />
      <button title="Fetch data" onClick={() => fetchUserCreds()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes you got me right. Thanks for the help. I made some changes in this code and that is working fine,  i am able to fetch the data from firestore and set it to the input box, but i am still facing an issue with updating the data in the firestore.

Comment: Can you explain more about the issue when updating data in firestore?

Comment: Also i have one more question that instead of useEffect what can i do to fetch the data and set it to the input box on button click ??

Comment: The issue is the data is not getting updated in the firestore.

Comment: I've changed the code so you can fetch the data when the button is clicked. When it comes to your data not updating, do you get any errors?

Comment: i solved this issue . i simply called the changeCreds on form submit and it worked. Thanks for all the help!